# Passing data into an Asp.Net Core bound model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an Asp.Net Core 2 project, whereby I'm trying to change the data in a class from a form; here's my form:

```
@model MyProject.Model
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = " ...";
}
. . . 
    <form asp-action="MyMethod" asp-controller="MyController">
        <input type="text" asp-for="MyClass.MyValue" />

    </form>
```

The referenced model looks like this:

```
public class Model
{
    public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }

    public Model(MyClass myClass)
    {
        MyClass = myClass
    }
```

The idea being that MyClass gets registered with the IoC initially, and its current value gets passed into the web page.  The user can then change the values and post it on to `MyController`.  The controller looks like this:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(Model myModel)
    {
```

However, when I execute this and call `MyMethod`, I get the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type
>   'Model'. Model bound complex
>   types must not be abstract or value types and must have a
>   parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'myModel'
>   parameter a non-null default value.
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.ComplexTypeModelBinder.CreateModel(ModelBindingContext
>   bindingContext)

So, it appears from the error that what I'm trying to do is explicitly prohibited by Asp.Net Core.  I'm curious as to why that is the case (since it has the object in the IoC), but this is presumably well trodden ground, so how can I pass this class in?

EDIT:

The class is registered in Startup.cs using the Asp.Net core IoC container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddTransient<MyClass, MyClass>();
```

Comment: Generally when using constructor injection you pass in an interface that your class implements. It appears you are passing on the class and when the container initializes the Model object it may know about IMyClass but not Myclass.

Comment: No - I'm registering the class as a specific object, not as an implementation of an interface

Comment: What container are you using? There are ways to pass in a constructor parameter when you register a service and if your service is registered correctly then it should not complain.

Comment: I've edited the question to include how the class is registered

Comment: @qwerty Unlike MVVM, `ViewModel` in MVC doesn't normally have dependencies. What does `MyClass` do? Could you show `MyMethod(Model myModel)` action method?

Comment: MyClass is just a place to store some data that I initially set on startup.

Comment: @qwerty Well, the answer is `ViewModel` should not depend on `MyClass`; DI container could not resolve the dependency inside ModelBinder.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to update model as below. You need to create default constructor as when we post complex model because during model binding engine can't identify with parameter constructor.

```
public class Model
{
    public MyClass MyClass { get; set; }
    public Model()
    {
        //MyClass = myClass;
    }
    public Model(MyClass myClass)
    {
        MyClass = myClass;
    }
}
```

My action method

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> MyMethod(Model myModel)
{
   //return View();
}
```

Comment: Whilst that does bypass the error, it looks like it just uses the default paramerless contructor (which makes sense), and therefore never gets the pre-registered instance of MyClass

Comment: Can you elaborate your comment. Here, i have tried to post complex model and its working fine in my example( as per your above questions, i have prepared demo and its working fine).

Comment: In ConfigureServices, I'm setting some initial values for MyClass; and those values are lost.  I assume this is because the IoC never actually resolves the registered version of MyClass, because it finds a paramerless constructor, and uses that

Comment: Don't have idea on that, but you can set default value of MyClass on hidden field when page load and Post when user click on button. (My initial thought)